# Find a sum of two distinct numbers from the set, closest to the query number

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Input:
>
> Input contains multiple cases. Each case starts with an integer n (1 <
> n  1000), which indicates, how many numbers are in the set of
> integer. Next n lines contain n numbers. Of course there is only one
> number in a single line. The next line contains a positive integer m
> giving the number of queries, 0 < m < 25. The next m lines contain an
> integer of the query, one per line. Input is terminated by a case
> whose n = 0. Surely, this case needs no processing.
>
> ---
>
> Output:
>
> Output should be organized as in the sample below. For each
> query output one line giving the query value and the closest sum in
> the format as in the sample. Inputs will be such that no ties will
> occur.

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//Prototype
void input_output(int n, int m);
int main (){

    int n=0; //Keep track of how many set of integers
    int m=0; //number of queries

    input_output(n, m);



    return 0;
}

//Prototype for the following function
int closest_sum(int n, int integers[], int query);

/* input_output: Output the correct data given by specific input
   intput: (int)number of integers, (int) number of queribes
   output: print out the correct cases without any return values*/
void input_output(int n, int m){
    //Counter for looping integers and queries arrays;
    int counter_n,counter_m;
    int case_val = 1; //Keep track of the case number
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(n!=0){
        printf("Case %d:\n", case_val);
        int integers[n]; //store value of integers
        for(counter_n = 0; counter_n < n; counter_n++){
            scanf("%d", &integers[counter_n]);
        }
        scanf("%d", &m);
        int queries[m];// store queries' value
        for(counter_m = 0; counter_m < m; counter_m++){
            scanf("%d", &queries[counter_m]);
            int closest=closest_sum(n, integers, queries[counter_m]);
            printf("Closest sum to %d is %d.\n", queries[counter_m], closest);
        }
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }
}

/* closest_sum: return a closest sum to the query base on the integers input
   intput: (int)integers input data array
   output: none(only return the value of the closest sum*/
int closest_sum(int n, int integers[], int query){
    //Store the difference of different sum related to query
    //Only at the start it will have negative number to show that it is first time
    int current_diff = -1;
    int current = integers[0];//Set a template number

    //Counter for outer and inner loop, add each element
    int outside,inside;

    //Loop for outer index
    for (outside = 0; outside < n; outside++){
        //Loop for outer index(note that inside equals to outside to avoid depucate sum
        for(inside=outside; inside < n-1; inside++){
            //Store new possiable variable for new sum
            int new_num = integers[outside]+integers[inside+1];
            //Check which one is greater between query and new number(Avoid Negative number)
            //If the difference between new_num and query is less than current
            //Set current to new number
            int different = 0;//stores the differents of two number
            if (new_num<query){
                different = query-new_num;
            }else{
                different = new_num-query;
            }
            //If the function just started to process assign current diff to the first different
            if (current_diff == -1){
                current_diff = different;
            }

            //Set current to new_num
            if(different<=current_diff){
                current=new_num;
                current_diff = different;
            }
        }
    }
    return current;
}
```

Sample Input:

> 5
> 3
> 12
> 17
> 33
> 34
> 3
> 1
> 51
> 30
> 3
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 3
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 3
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> 0

Sample Output:

> Case 1:
> Closest sum to 1 is 15.
> Closest sum to 51 is 51.
> Closest sum to 30 is 29.
>
> Case 2:
> Closest sum to 1 is 3.
> Closest sum to 2 is 3.
> Closest sum to 3 is 3.
>
> Case 3:
> Closest sum to 4 is 4.
> Closest sum to 5 is 5.
> Closest sum to 6 is 5.

Although I got my code working, I think there are still some missing piece into it. First off, my code have a high complexity for some reason and also it takes a while for it to compile. Could anyone please give me some suggestions to improve my code? Thanks.

(Besides, is it a good idea to use a while loop to ask for user's input all the time?)

Comment: You can use binary search to make every query solved in `O(nlogn)`

Comment: @F.Ju I understand the sorting i can do better on it. What else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First, input the `n` number of integers into an array.
2. Sort them in `O(n.log(n))` time.
3. Now, for each query of `m`, do as follows:

   ```
   /*     arr => array holds sorted values    */

   int low  = 0;               // Lower Index of an array
   int high = length;          // Upper Index of an array

   int query_value;            // Input from the user
   int near_value;             // Near Value to be calculated
   int difference = INT_MAX;   // difference between near_value and query_value
   int temp;

   while(low < high) {
       temp = arr[low] + arr[high];

       if(temp == query_value) {
           near_value = query_value;
           break;
       } else if(temp < query_value) {
           if(abs(temp - query_value) < difference) {
               difference = abs(temp - query_value);
               near_value = temp;
           }

           low++;
       } else {
           if(abs(temp - query_value) < difference) {
               difference = abs(temp - query_value);
               near_value = temp;
           }

           high--;
       }
   }

   print near_value;          // Print the near_value calculated
   ```

Now, let's talk about **time complexity**. Since, we are sorting the array first, and then for each `m` query, we are calculating its `near_value` in `O(n)` linear time.

Therefore, the net time complexity will be : **O(n.log(n) + n.m)**. *(NOTE: the number of rounds are not included).*