# How to find a pair of numbers in the array which sum is closest to x with O(n) time complexity?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

Given a `sorted array` and a number `x`, find a pair in that array whose sum is closest to x". How can we implement this with `O(n)` time complexity?

Example:

```
fn([10,22,28,29,30,40], 54)  // => [22, 30]

fn([1,3,4,7,10], 15)  // => [4, 10]

fn([5], 7)  // => []

fn([], 7)  // => []
```

**Update:**

It was my latest try to solve this problem, which isn't working and it has O(n^2) time complexity.

```js
function fn(arr, x) {
  let res = [];
  if (arr.length < 2) return res;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = arr.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
      let t = Math.abs(arr[i] + arr[j] - x);
      if (arr[i] + arr[j] === x) return (res = [arr[i], arr[j]]);
      if (arr[i] + arr[j] > x) {
        if (t > Math.abs(arr[i] + arr[j] - x)) {
          t = Math.abs(arr[i] + arr[j] - x);
          res = [arr[i], arr[j]];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(fn([10, 22, 28, 29, 30, 40], 54));
console.log(fn([1, 3, 4, 7, 10], 15));
```

Comment: How would you solve this problem with pencil and paper? Now translate that technique into code.

Comment: I don't know how to answer this question. I would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a sum of two distinct numbers from the set, closest to the query number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885022/find-a-sum-of-two-distinct-numbers-from-the-set-closest-to-the-query-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is very simple. To follow along from a very safe position, we will first try the farthest numbers.

```
1 2 3 4 5
^       ^
l       r
```

Now we have different cases. Let's be the difference between the sum of two num and the given number is `d`

At first we would allow any `d`. Set it a very large number.

Then if sum of `a[l]+a[r] < x` then try to increase it? So it would be logical to move towards right of the sorted (ascending array) `l++`

Else if it is `a[l]+a[r] > x`, `r--` so reduce the sum or move left.

If you are wondering why did I introduce `d`, maybe think a bit. But yes it is just to store the difference. So it would be **absolute** value of `a[l]+a[r]-x`.

To be more precise, you only need to run it till you have `l<r`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful guide. How can I think like this?

Comment: @ZahraMirzaei I think with time you will think way better than this. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in javascript code:

```js
function fn(arr, x) {
  let res = [];
  if (arr.length < 2) return res;

  let i = 0,
    j = arr.length - 1,
    t = Math.abs(arr[i] + arr[j] - x);
    
  while (i < j) {
    let s = arr[i] + arr[j];
    
    if (s === t) {
      res = [arr[i], arr[j]];
      break;
    }
    
    if (s < x) {
      i++;
      if (Math.abs(arr[i] + arr[j] - x) < t) {
        t = Math.abs(arr[i] + arr[j] - x);
        res = [arr[i], arr[j]];
      }
    }
    
    if (s > x) {
      j--;
      if (Math.abs(arr[i] + arr[j] - x) < t) {
        t = Math.abs(arr[i] + arr[j] - x);
        res = [arr[i], arr[j]];
      }
    }
    
  }
  
  return res;
}

console.log(fn([10, 22, 28, 29, 30, 40], 54));
console.log(fn([1, 3, 4, 7, 10], 15));
console.log(fn([5], 7));
console.log(fn([], 7));
```